# Stop external program when Java program is stopped

Tags: java, executable

I'm executing an external program which runs alongside Java using this:

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/path/to/binary");
```

When I stop the Java application, the external program continues to run but I want this to stop too.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get rid of Java child processes when my Java app exits/crashes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261125/how-do-i-get-rid-of-java-child-processes-when-my-java-app-exits-crashes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To trigger the shutdown, you could add a shutdown hook to your Java application. See [Runtime.addShutdownHook()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29).

To effect the shutdown, you could either communicate to the external process a request to stop gracefully, or call Process.destroy()

Answer (score 1):

use shutdown hook : http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/lang/hook-design.html