# Stop child processes after main program exits in java

Tags: java, ubuntu, process, processbuilder, process-management

I have written a Java program to run some other processes for special tasks. I want to satisfy a grate condition which is all child processes should exit if the main java process ended or exited. I used this code in my java program:

```
processBuilder = new ProcessBuilder(command);
processBuilder.redirectErrorStream(true);
process = processBuilder.start();
```

I see sometimes this won't happen. Sample command to execute may be calling a program or shell file. I used `waitFor()` but it was not effective. I use Ubuntu 12.04 and java 7.21. Can anybody help me about this?

**EDIT:** 
I want the child process be stopped by the OS even if main java process exited unexpectedly.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I get rid of Java child processes when my Java app exits/crashes?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/261125/how-do-i-get-rid-of-java-child-processes-when-my-java-app-exits-crashes)

Comment: The solution specified there is using `shutdownhook`. I want the child process be stopped by the OS even if java process exited unexpectedly.

Comment: I believe the **question** I linked is the same as yours; but I agree the **answer** is unsatisfactory. Perhaps the use of a wrapper (see e.g. http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/doc/english/index.html ) can help? I have withdrawn my "close" flag - let's see if someone comes up with a better answer than "it can't be done".