# Do you need to close a process opened by Java?

Tags: java, operating-system, jvm

Consider the following:

`new ProcessBuilder(pathToSomeExectuable).start();`

What will happen when the current Java application will be closed? In other words, is the `Process` running as daemon and will automatically closed? Or, do I need to call `destroy()`?

Comment: if you're on linux run `watch "ps aux | grep myExecutableName"` then start you're program `new ProcessBuilder(pathToSomeExectuable).start();` and then monitor what happens once the java application has terminated. If it is still alive you need to make an exit call manually otherwise not. If you're on windows use the task manager

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[At least on linux] the subprocess aren't automatically terminated when the parent process exits.

Read these resources for more information:

- [Are child processes created with fork() automatically killed when the parent is killed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/395877/are-child-processes-created-with-fork-automatically-killed-when-the-parent-is)
- [How do I get rid of Java child processes when my Java app exits/crashes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/261125/how-do-i-get-rid-of-java-child-processes-when-my-java-app-exits-crashes)