# Writing a long lived Java class that can be stopped from a different JVM

Tags: java

I am looking for any tutorial/example that shows the best practices for one to write a standalone Java class that will run like a server (w/o exiting) and can be stopped by issuing another command from a different invocation of the JVM (sort of like a Tomcat server). Is the best way to look for classes in java.util.concurrent as there are some interesting classes there such as CountDownLatch? An example would be really helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what you're looking for.

Here is a trivial server that will happily count to MAXINT and back again until it's stopped.

You can use JConsole to stop it.

Server.java

```
import javax.management.*;
import java.lang.management.*;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class Server implements ServerMBean {
    AtomicBoolean running;

    public void register() throws Exception {
        MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
        ObjectName serverBeanName = null;
        serverBeanName = new ObjectName("ServerBean:name=TestBean");
        mbs.registerMBean(this, serverBeanName);
    }

    public void stop() {
        running.set(false);
    }

    public void runServer() throws Exception {
        int cnt = 0;
        running = new AtomicBoolean(true);
        while(running.get()) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.println("tic tic " + cnt++);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Server bean = new Server();
        bean.register();
        bean.runServer();
    }
}
```

ServerMBean.java

```
public interface ServerMBean {
    public void stop();
}
```

This registers a trivial JMX MBean that has a single method (stop), which sets the running variable to "false" and thus stops the loop. Note that 'running' is an AtomicBoolean, as that is important. If you used a normal boolean it is quite possible this would never stop. It would work also with a volatile boolean.

If you start the server (java Server) and then fire up JConsole, it will offer Server as a process to connect to. Then go to the MBeans tab, find ServerBean -> TestBean -> Operations -> stop in the tree view, and click the stop button, and the server will stop.

What you want your server to do, I dunno. But this gives you a taste of what can be done in, what, 40 lines of code...

Comment: Thanks for a good example. How would one go about having this type of logic w/o calling Thread.sleep() ?

Comment: Actually this gives me more ideas now. I can simply use CountdownLatch(1) instead of AtomicBoolean and in the stop method call the countDown() method.

Comment: The Thread.sleep was just there to pause the simple loop. You don't want to use a CountDownLatch. CountDownLatches are one time switches that are better used to hold things up, rather than stop things later. I have several threads waiting on a single CDL for the main system to initialize everything, then I set the latch to 0 and they're off to the races. Once its set to 0, you can't reset it. The AtomicBoolean is a good choice for this as its simply global state telling the main loop to run.

Answer (score 0):

[JMX](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/overview.html) can be a solution for remotely controlling a Java application. This  [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191215/how-to-stop-java-process-gracefully/208809#208809) provides details of a JMX based solution for shutting down a JVM.

Note that JMX makes it possible to control your application over the network too. If you don't want to risk a malicious remote shutdown, you'll have to [secure the access to the JMX interface](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/guide/jmx/tutorial/security.html). Though a firewall rule to block access to JMX port might be good enough in low risk environments.