# What is a clean / recommended way to terminate a perpetually-running command-line Java application?

Tags: java, shell, command-line, command-line-interface

More specifically, I have a multithreaded command line Java application which runs and collects data until the user terminates it.

The obvious way for the user to terminate it is by pushing Control-C, but then I need to install a shutdown hook in the VM and deal with all the threads.

Is there a nicer / more appropriate way for the user to inform the application that it's time to shutdown?

For example, is there a way to capture some other key combination and set a boolean flag in my application?

As a further clarification, I seek something functionally similar to signal handling in C.

Comment: I don't know whether this is proper or not: extend Thread's `run() { while(!isInterrupted()) { /* run your java codes here */ }}}` Then, call `interrupt()` for the extended Thread class.

Comment: you cannot rely on shutdown hook.look at Java Monitoring and Management

Comment: @merlin: again merlin ,according to your question you want graceful ( clean up the resources and say bye bye and come out ) .if you want to detect abnormal  termination , you need to handle outside JVM boundary i.e. at OS level. To detect whether your process launch java process inside a Perl script, but have the script wait for the JVM using the waitpid system call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way can be to create a new thread which will "listen" to standard input. Based on whatever key pattern you decide, that thread can set the flag in the main application.

Comment: I thought about this too, but having a thread just listening to standard in feels hackish too. Does anyone know of a more kosher way to do this?

Comment: do not believe in thread. What if OS silently kills the thread that is listening.

Comment: What i said is a worst scenario when OS may have blocked your process for some time.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a nicer / more appropriate way for the user to inform the
>   application that it's time to shutdown?

The best way is to use [Java Monitoring and Management](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/management/overview.html)

Look at this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191215/how-to-stop-java-process-gracefully) for example.

It is best not to rely on shutdown hook.Shutdown hook in java works for `KILL -15` AND `KILL`  and do not work for `KILL -9` (**HARD KILL**)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using shutdown hook like this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(shutdownHook);
```

to have your own code that runs whenever the JVM terminates under 1 of the following conditions:

1. The program exits normally, such as when the last non-daemon thread exits or when the Runtime.exit() method is invoked.
2. The virtual machine is terminated in response to a user interrupt, such as typing CTRL-C, or a system-wide event, such as user logoff or system shutdown (for example, the JVM receives one of the interrupt signals SIGHUP (Unix Only), SIGINT, or SIGTERM).

You can refer to: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/ibm/library/i-signalhandling/ for more details (Disclaimer: very old article pertains to JDK 1.3.1)

Comment: When do the other threads run with respect to the shutdown hook's running time? That is, does the shutdown hook or the VM wait for active threads to finish?

Comment: If a non-daemon thread is running then JVM does wait for that thread to finish before exiting.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a Java specific solution but (atleast on Linux) during shutdown, the operating system sends a `SIGTERM` to all processes (following by a SIGKILL after a grace period). Your application should install a handler for this and then shutdown gracefully. Once you do this, it will automatically take care of itself when you shutdown your VM.

Comment: I've never coded in Java so I don't know. But if this is on a UNIX, this seems to be the right way to do it.

Comment: @merlin2011 - according to anubhava's answer, yes.