# Enable SIGTERM in SecurityManager

Tags: java, security

My custom security manager currently blocks graceful closing due to SIGTERMs. The follow message is displayed:

> Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM warning: Exception java.lang.SecurityException occurred dispatching signal SIGTERM to handler- the VM may need to be forcibly terminated

What should I do to enable shutting down due to SIGTERMS but nothing more?

Comment: Do you know which check method your SecurityManager is causing that exception? As far as I can tell, the relevant one is: checkPermission(java.lang.RuntimePermission shutdownHooks)

Comment: Sorry, 2 others: checkAccess() with the "system" thread group, and checkAccess() with the SIGTERM handler thread within the "system" threadgroup. Is your SecurityManager preventing these accesses?

Comment: It has everything disabled at the moment.

Comment: You've probably look at this but just in case. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/191215/how-to-stop-java-process-gracefully

Comment: Then you need to allow checkPermission() for the name "shutdownHooks", allow checkAccess() for the *system* thread group and the *SIGTERM handler* thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your implementation has probably disabled the full debugging information from `-Djava.security.debug=all` if you omit to call `super.checkAccess`. If you write first in your `SecurityManager` implementation

```
  public void checkAccess(ThreadGroup g) {
      System.out.println("Access for " + g);
      super.checkAccess(g);
  }
  public void checkAccess(Thread t) {
      System.out.println("Access for " + t);
      super.checkAccess(t);
  }
```

and run with `-Djava.security.debug=all`, you get information about `checkAccess` calls to allow and permissions to add to your policy file. I sum up:

```
Access for java.lang.ThreadGroup[name=system,maxpri=10]
Permission (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThreadGroup)
[...]
Access for Thread[SIGTERM handler,9,system]
Permission (java.lang.RuntimePermission modifyThread)
[...]
 java.security.Permissions@133c5982 (
 (java.lang.RuntimePermission exitVM)
 (java.io.FilePermission /path/to/current/working/directory/- read)
)
```

As a result, you enable `SIGTERM` signal handling the stricter way with the following code in your `SecurityManager`:

```
  public void checkAccess(ThreadGroup g) {
      System.out.println("Access for " + g);
      if ("system".equals(g.getName()))  {
         // will checkPermission java.lang.RuntimePermission "modifyThreadGroup"
         super.checkAccess(g);
      } else {
         throw new SecurityException("Access denied to " + g);
      }
  }

  public void checkAccess(Thread t) {
      System.out.println("Access for " + t);
      if ("SIGTERM handler".equals(t.getName())) {
         // will checkPermission java.lang.RuntimePermission "modifyThread"
         super.checkAccess(t);
      } else {
         throw new SecurityException("Access denied to " + t);
      }
  }
```

And also these permissions granting in your `java.security.policy` file:

```
grant {
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "modifyThreadGroup";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "modifyThread";
  permission java.lang.RuntimePermission "exitVM";
};
```

The full information is available [here](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/appB.html) but it is really not obvious to do it right, the try-and-fix method is still the fastest way.