# How to terminate JVM run from shell script?

Tags: java, linux, shell

I have a shell script starting two java processes. How to ensure that when shell script process is killed, all It's children will be killed too? For example when I try to kill It, java processes remain alive:

```
kill -9 myscriptID
```

Comment: I hope `myscript` refers to its process-id here.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for all java processes by running this:

```
ps -aux | grep *java*
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191215/how-to-stop-java-process-gracefully) looks like it can help as well.

Answer (score 0):

Your `kill` command only kills your script, not other processes that it has spawned.  [Best way to kill all child processes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/392022/best-way-to-kill-all-child-processes) has some great answers for killing the whole tree.

That said, it seems that a better design would be to keep track of the PIDs of the child processes, and rather than sending the parent `SIGKILL`, send it `SIGTERM` (or have some other way) to trigger it to gracefully kill its children.