# addshutdownHook is not invoked when sending a QUIT signal

Tags: java, shutdown-hook, application-shutdown

I would like to terminate the Java application when 'kill -s 3 ' is executed. But Java dumps the thread information instead. Do I need to use different kill signal?

Comment: what **resource** you want to clean up using shutdownhook?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [JVMs and kill signals](http://journal.thobe.org/2013/02/jvms-and-kill-signals.html), the ShutdownHook is not run and the jvm is not shutdown when using signal SIGQUIT (3). 
Just use the default signal SIGTERM (15).

Answer (score 0):

whats wrong with just kill? it shold send the default signal, SIGTERM

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this:
[How to stop java process gracefully?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191215/how-to-stop-java-process-gracefully)

kill -3 or kill -s 3 will always generate the thread dump.

In general programming, finalizer and shutdownhooks should not be used.