# Java - catch PC is turning off event, or equivalent

Tags: java, events, exit, shutdown

I created a software which edits some XML files. When a file is opened a lock file is generated to avoid having multiple users editing the file at the same moment.

I would like now to be able to delete such a lock if someone turns the PC off. (The application runs on both Linux and Windows.)

Is there any common signal which is passed to the Virtual machine when attempting to close the current section?

Cheers,
Ste

Comment: isn´t the lock deleted on shutdown?

Comment: nono, te losk is a simple rudimental text file that i create in a common folder. because the tool is webstarted on the same resourced by many people on different machine.

Comment: ah, okay, then you`re right ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to add a [shutdown hook](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29):

```
final Thread mainThread = Thread.currentThread();
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        // remove lock file...
    }
});
```

In this case the code in the `run`-method will be executed before termination of the JVM. (Unless the JVM is killed with something like `kill -9 31337`.)

**Related question:**

- [Useful example of a shutdown hook in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921945/useful-example-of-a-shutdown-hook-in-java)

Comment: Little problem... since i am creatig another thred i guess only static methon can be called. I have instad a mathod removeLocksOnExit(); in the main class which i would like to refere. Do you know what could i do in this case?

Comment: No problems calling non-static methods from other threads... don't know where you got that from...

Comment: i posted it on another question.. just to make it more clear. here the link:

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256620/java-call-a-non-static-method-from-shutdownhook

Comment: The event is not triggered. do i have to add anything else?

Answer (score 0):

Standard [Runtime.addShutdownHook(...)](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29)

More advanced technique using JNI,
[How do I get my Java application to shutdown nicely in windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61692/how-do-i-get-my-java-application-to-shutdown-nicely-in-windows)