# Java Exit on Windows Shutdown

Tags: java, exit

I have this code. I want to exit my Java Application if it detects that the computer is shutting down. I have this problem, If shutdown is clicked on windows my java application disconnects from android app connection. I want to display that the java application has been disconnected or it will exit.

```
//  Copyright 2012
//  Android Remote Desktop Server Ver. 1.0


import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.Random;

public class ServerWindow implements ActionListener{

    private RemoteDataServer server;

    private Thread sThread; //server thread

    private static final int WINDOW_HEIGHT = 200;
    private static final int WINDOW_WIDTH = 350;

    private String ipAddress;

    private JFrame window = new JFrame("Remote Control for Android");

    private JLabel addressLabel = new JLabel("");
    private JLabel portLabel = new JLabel("Android Remote Control Port: ");
    private JTextArea[] buffers = new JTextArea[3];
    private JTextField portTxt = new JTextField(5);
    private JLabel serverMessages = new JLabel("Not Connected");

    private JButton connectButton = new JButton("Start Server");
    private JButton disconnectButton = new JButton("Stop Server");

    public boolean connected = false;




    //@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    public ServerWindow(){
        server = new RemoteDataServer();

        window.setSize(WINDOW_WIDTH, WINDOW_HEIGHT);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        connectButton.addActionListener(this);
        disconnectButton.addActionListener(this);

        Container c = window.getContentPane();
        c.setLayout(new FlowLayout());

        try{
            InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            ipAddress = ip.getHostAddress();
            addressLabel.setText("Android Remote Control Server IP Address: "+ipAddress);
        }
        catch(Exception e){addressLabel.setText("IP Address Could Not be Resolved");}

        int x;
        for(x = 0; x < 3; x++){
            buffers[x] = new JTextArea("", 1, 30);
            buffers[x].setEditable(false);
            buffers[x].setBackground(window.getBackground());
        }

        portTxt.setEditable(false);
        Random portRandom = new Random();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

          int port = portRandom.nextInt(4998) + 1;
          int portNum = 5000+port;
          String portString = Integer.toString(portNum);
          portTxt.setText(portString);
          }

        c.add(addressLabel);
        c.add(buffers[0]);
        c.add(portLabel);
        //portTxt.setText("5444");
        c.add(portTxt);
        c.add(buffers[1]);
        c.add(connectButton);
        c.add(disconnectButton);
        c.add(buffers[2]);
        c.add(serverMessages);

        window.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        window.setVisible(true);
        window.setResizable(false);

    }


    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
        Object src = e.getSource();

        if(src instanceof JButton){
            if((JButton)src == connectButton){
                int port = Integer.parseInt(portTxt.getText());
                runServer(port);
            }

            else if((JButton)src == disconnectButton){
                closeServer();
            }
        }
    }

    public void runServer(int port){
        if(port <= 9999){
            server.setPort(port);
            sThread = new Thread(server);
            sThread.start();
        }
        else{
            serverMessages.setText("The port Number must be less than 10000");
        }
    }

    public void closeServer(){
        serverMessages.setText("Disconnected");
        server.shutdown();
        connectButton.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        new ServerWindow();
    }

    public class RemoteDataServer implements Runnable{
        int PORT;
        private DatagramSocket server;
        private byte[] buf;
        private DatagramPacket dgp;

        private String message;
        private AutoBot bot;

        public RemoteDataServer(int port){
            PORT = port;
            buf = new byte[1000];
            dgp = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            bot = new AutoBot();
            serverMessages.setText("Not Connected");
        }

        public RemoteDataServer(){
            buf = new byte[1000];
            dgp = new DatagramPacket(buf, buf.length);
            bot = new AutoBot();
            serverMessages.setText("Not Connected");
        }

        public String getIpAddress(){
            String returnStr;
            try{
                    InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost();
                    returnStr = ip.getCanonicalHostName();
            }
            catch(Exception e){ returnStr = new String("Could Not be Resolve Ip Address");}
            return returnStr;
        }

        public void setPort(int port){
            PORT = port;
        }

        public void shutdown(){
            try{server.close();
                serverMessages.setText("Disconnected");}
            catch(Exception e){}
        }
        public void run(){
            //boolean connected = false;
            try {InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost(); 
                serverMessages.setText("Waiting for connection on " + ip.getCanonicalHostName());

                server = new DatagramSocket(PORT, ip);

                connected = true;
                connectButton.setEnabled(false);
            }
            catch(BindException e){ serverMessages.setText("Port "+PORT+" is already in use. Use a different Port"); }
            catch(Exception e){serverMessages.setText("Unable to connect");}

            while(connected){
                //Runtime.getRuntime().exit(0);
                // get message from sender
                try{ server.receive(dgp);

                    // translate and use the message to automate the desktop
                    message = new String(dgp.getData(), 0, dgp.getLength());
                    if (message.equals("Connectivity")){
                        //send response to confirm connectivity
                        serverMessages.setText("Trying to Connect");
                        server.send(dgp); //echo the message back
                    }else if(message.equals("Connected")){
                        server.send(dgp); //echo the message back
                    }else if(message.equals("Close")){
                        serverMessages.setText("Controller has Disconnected. Trying to reconnect."); //echo the message back
                    }else{
                        serverMessages.setText("Android Phone Connected to ARD Server");
                        bot.handleMessage(message);
                    }
                }catch(Exception e){
                    serverMessages.setText("Disconnected");
                    connected = false;}
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats quite a lot of code you posted. Are you sure all of it is relevant?

Comment: Is my understanding correct here, you would like to detect whenever Windows is being shut down using Java?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming that the question you meant to ask is "how to detect when Windows is being shut down", here is how you do it:

You need a so-called "System Shutdown Hook", which is essentially a Thread who's run() method is executed whenever the Java virtual machine shuts down. The happens either when your program terminates or because of a system-wide event, such as a user log-off or a shut-down.

All you need to do is put this piece of code somewhere in the startup process of your program:

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            // this is executed on shut-down. put whatever.
        }
    }));
```

I hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks sir, but i don't really have an idea where to put that codes. I am only a beginner in Android Programming. Can you specify where part of the program will I put that codes? Thank you Very much sir.

Comment: @user1753530 Like I said, you need to put it somewhere within the intialization phase. Since the actions you would like to perform when Windows is being shut-down require an open network connection (as far as I understood), you should put that code right after you set-up the server (I believe right after the `server = new RemoteDataServer();` would be appropriate). Within that `run()` method you then call your shutdown script.

Comment: Server Window did not respond if shutdown was initiated then canceled. I need to at least exit my Java Program before the windows force shutdown. It has "application preventing from windows to shutdown" alert. Please help me. I need a code for this. Thanks

Comment: @user1753530 Although I don't really have much experience with shutdown hooks, this alert window should go away after a second or two if the script you put in the ´run()´ method of the code I gave you executes considerably fast, which it should. Check whether its execution really does terminate at some point, or if it gets stuck in a loop of some sort. -- If the problem persists, post your updated code and reply to this comment so I know.

Comment: I didn't change anything except i add a shutdown hood to run() method as what you have said. Please help me Sir, I don't know why it does not respond, even exit,minimize and maximize is disable when it comes from an force shutdown mode then canceled. Thanks

Comment: Best solution known to me are C/C++ implemented wrappers to start / stop java applications running as service (server like Tomcat as Windows service etc). But in this situation is impossible to distinct stopping service "by hand" or with whole Windows. Pure Java can't detect such shutdown

Comment: Note that this answer does not work, or does not work anymore on JDK 17 / Windows 11. If you have a Java Swing application open, and click logout / shutdown / restart in the Start Menu, then the application will shutdown instantly and none of your shutdown hooks are called.

Comment: Here's a solution that'll work with recent Windows 10 / 11 and JDK releases: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77160942/1514467