# Detecting when pc is turning off from java daemon

Tags: java, runtime, listener, daemon

I have developed a Java daemon and I want to create a kind of listener which will be called when the PC is turning off in way to check some Application info.

If you have some info about it, let me know. Is it possible to control the shutting down process of OS. How could I get info of shutting down process of OS in Java?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991116/java-exit-on-windows-shutdown

Comment: Show way, library,  how You integrate java app with OS (Windows?)

Comment: Cited link isn't solution (is only partially solution), not adequate to this question