# Java shutdown hook call on windows shut down

Tags: java, windows, native, shutdown-hook

I have a situation in which I want to perform some task when the user signals the OS(in my case only Windows) to shutdown.

I have tried using java shutdown hooks. The problem I face is that when I exit the program using `System.exit(0);`, the shutdown hooks are called but when I directly shutdown the computer, they aren't.

This is the code I have used for the shutdown hooks-

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new JVMShutdownHook()); //in main method

//within the main java class
private static class JVMShutdownHook extends Thread {
@Override
public void run() {
   //perform tasks
}
}
```

Is there any way to interact with the OS(I'm assuming some native code) so that it allows my program to exit gracefully?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Look at something like the JNA api, they probably have a os shutdown hook available

Comment: No luck so far. There is a method `Native.setProtected(true)` in the JNA API to prevent the VM from crashing but i'm not able to get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

`ShutdownHooks` indeed do not work by shutdown of Windows. I consider it as a bug of Java and opened a BugReport last week. It has however not (yet) been published.

There was an old Bug Report in 2008: [Runtime#addShutdownHook does not work on Windows Vista, when user logs out](http://bugs.java.com/view_bug.do?bug_id=6667751). The same problem occurs with Windows 7. The ticket was closed by java.com without a satifying response.

Windows gives by shutdown some time to the applications to terminate gracefully. The delay is defined by the registry key `WaitToKillApplication`. I expect the java program uses this delay to execute the hooks (and the finalizes if `Runtime.runFinalizersOnExit()` is set).

Let see if Oracle recognizes it as a bug...

Comment: You can use `sun.misc.Signal` nowadays too hook into the `WM_QUERYENDSESSION` code, still no proper public API though: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77160942/1514467

Answer (score 1):

I had to implement this for a Windows deployed application a couple years back using JDK 11.

Regarding [the linked answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61692/how-do-i-get-my-java-application-to-shutdown-nicely-in-windows/77285560#77285560) you could create a better suited implementation for this context.

I originally posted my answer there to be at available for both questions but it had a different context as in showing UI elements which are not suppsed to be used in my implementation (as I was pointed out). Since there is no such requirement in this case I think the one I describe is the most straightforward implementation and a proper "enough" API to use.

You can directly use the respective classes even if they are part of the internal API since they are not strongly encapsulated.

See this [JEP403](https://openjdk.org/jeps/403) for details:

> It is not a goal to remove, encapsulate, or modify any critical
> internal APIs of the JDK for which standard replacements do not yet
> exist. This means that sun.misc.Unsafe will remain available.

Whereas on the linked JEP the following is stated:

> Critical internal APIs not encapsulated in JDK 9
>
> The critical internal APIs that are not encapsulated in JDK 9, because
> supported replacements did not exist in JDK 8, are listed here.
>
> - sun.misc.{Signal,SignalHandler}

And also all currently supported (as of writing this post) LTS JDKs support the feature of raising a `TERM` signal on `WM_QUERYENDSESSION`. Sadly I cannot link the documentation for that, but I can link the source code references:
[OpenJDK 8](https://github.com/frohoff/jdk8u-jdk/blob/da0da73ab82ed714dc5be94acd2f0d00fbdfe2e9/src/windows/native/sun/windows/awt_Toolkit.cpp#L1049C15-L1049C30),
[OpenJDK 11](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk11/blob/master/src/java.desktop/windows/native/libawt/windows/awt_Toolkit.cpp#L1271),
[OpenJDK 17](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk17/blob/master/src/java.desktop/windows/native/libawt/windows/awt_Toolkit.cpp#L1299),
[OpenJDK 21](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk21/blob/master/src/java.desktop/windows/native/libawt/windows/awt_Toolkit.cpp#L1300).

Based on the above you can create a more simple implementation without using reflection (and exception handling because of that):

```
Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(/* Add your implementation here! */);
SignalHandler handler = (Signal sig) -> {
    System.exit(0);
};
Signal.handle(new Signal("TERM"), handler);
```

This would work in the way that once the shutdown sequence is started your shutdown logic will be invoked. The current implementation and documented JEPs will also ensure this also happens on `WM_QUERYENDSESSION`. This will remain the case until this API is publicly available (which is at least the end of support date of JDK 21).

With this solution you do not have to use platform dependent libraries and any class names specified in `String` literals, only the name of the `Signal` but AFAIK there is no workaround for that. (You could also add support for `TERM` the same way.)

Answer (score 0):

You will have to write native methods. Two for adding and removing your shutdown hook, and one that will act as a callback method for the hook, from where java code will be invoked. 
You hook will have to listen for OS shutting down message and invoke your callback when this occure. This is the way that plenty of apps that prevents windows from going into sleep mode or running screen saver works.

Check for some information about JNI here

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/jniTOC.html

and about hooks here

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx